# Why does Socket.io emit empty events at random intervals?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

[image]

I have an application that runs on Nodejs and Socket.io

The events 2, 3 seen in the image are empty events that socket.io server keeps emitting at random intervals. What's more annoying is that the time delay between the empty events is crazy, as seen in the picture there was a 19 seconds time delay between 2 and 3. And due to this, the message:delete event that was emitted by socket.io client which was supposed to immediately emit message:deleted, got delayed by 19 seconds!!

What's worse is that while these empty events are emitted, all other socket events originated from socket client are not emitted and they are stuck in limbo until the empty events are out of the way.

I suspect these empty events are socket `ping` and `pong` events. Does anyone have any idea why this happens? And how we could prevent this? Or maybe even set a priority for client socket.emit so that regardless of these empty events, the client emitted socket event takes precedence and is fired immediately?

Edit #1

Despite adding `{ transports : ['websocket'] }` the delay was still well over 17 seconds as you can see in this image

[image]

Edit #2 - The socket.emit code

The client is made up of a lot of jQuery + vanilla JS + Angular 1.7. The client socket is a factory wrapper

```
app.factory('socket',['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect('',{
    path: '/socket.io',
    transports: ['websocket']
});
return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        })
    },
    disconnect: function(close){
        socket.disconnect(close);
    },
    removeAllListeners: function (eventName, callback) {
        socket.removeAllListeners(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    }
};
}])
```

And on the controller the `socket.emit' code is as follows

```
$scope.deleteMessage = function (message) {
  socket.emit('message:delete', {
    id: message
  });
};
```

I use express + Nodejs so here's the code for initializing the server socket

```
Server = require('socket.io'),
io = new Server({
  path: `/socket.io`,
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

And the server side socket code listens to the client emit as follows

```
io.on("connection", async function (socket) {
  socket.on("message:delete", function (payload) {
    if (props.connectedUsers[socket.userId].info.isAdmin) {
      console.log("Received Message Deletion by", 
      props.connectedUsers[socket.userId].info.name);

      if (payload.id == "SYS_MOTD") return;
      await Message.remove({
        _id: new db.Types.ObjectId(payload.id)
      }).exec(function (err, message) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log("Emit message:deleted");
          io.sockets.emit("message:deleted", {
            id: payload.id
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Check it without the db query, if there's still a delay

Comment: Yeah it has the same delay

Answer (score 1):

I think it's normal, according to the Socket.IO [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-websocket-transport-only):

> By default, a long-polling connection is established first, then
>   upgraded to “better” transports (like WebSocket).

What you can do is to set the connection to use websocket only, it should stop the long-polling and you will receive the messages immediately:

```
socket = io.connect({transports: ['websocket']});
```

**Update**

No need to set the `path` to `/socket.io`, it's the [default value](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server-path-value).

On [Client](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) side you can also use:

```
const socket = io([URL], {
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

I've noticed you are using `async/await` with a `callback`, I would either use `async/await` or a `callback` on your server side code, for example:

```
try {
  await Message.remove({
    _id: new db.Types.ObjectId(payload.id)
  })
  console.log("Emit message:deleted");
  io.sockets.emit("message:deleted", {
    id: payload.id
  });
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
}
```

Comment: I am afraid I already tried that and it didn't change anything. The delay after explicitly adding 'websocket' transports was well over 17 seconds

Comment: Have you added it to both server and client side? Could you add the emit code to the question?

Comment: Yes, I have it on both client and server. Please check the code I've added under Edit #2